# pandas aggregate list with % for each group

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe like as below

```
name,id
    A 1
    A 2
    B 5
    B 5
    B 4
    C 6
```

I like to do the below

a) Group by `name`

b) create a list of unique `id` values for each `name`

c) populate the list with `% of occurrence` for each `id` under each group. For ex: `id=5` appears 2 times out of 3 records (for name = B). So, it's percentage will be 66.66%

d) Sort the resulting list items based on `%`

I tried the below

```
df.groupby('name')['id'].agg(list) #get list of ids for each name
df.groupby('name')['id'].agg(set)  #get unique ids for each name
df.groupby('name')['id'].nunique()
df.groupby('name')['id'].count()
```

But this doesn't give the % of `id` values for each group.

I have a big data of 5 million rows and any efficient solution is helpful

I expect my output to be like as below. List items sorted based on `%`.

```
A [1 - 50%,2 - 50%]
B [5 - 66.66%,4 - 33%]
C [6 - 100%]
```

Comment: I think `df.groupby('name')['id'].apply(pd.Series.value_counts, normalize=True)` gives you all the information you're after?

Comment: but how do we convert that output into expected output format that I have shown?

Comment: Currently, it shows multiple rows for each name. But I would like to have one row for each name..

Comment: okay... and how many columns?

Comment: You could add an `.unstack()` but that'll give N columns on the number of unique IDs so it might go quite wide...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use lambda function with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = df.groupby('name')['id'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True).tolist())
print (df)
name
A                                  [0.5, 0.5]
B    [0.6666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333]
C                                       [1.0]
Name: id, dtype: object
```

---

```
d = {i: x.value_counts(normalize=True).to_dict() for i, x in df.groupby('name')['id']}
print (d)
{'A': {1: 0.5, 2: 0.5}, 'B': {5: 0.6666666666666666, 4: 0.3333333333333333}, 'C': {6: 1.0}}

s = pd.Series(d)
print (s)
A                                  {1: 0.5, 2: 0.5}
B    {5: 0.6666666666666666, 4: 0.3333333333333333}
C                                          {6: 1.0}
dtype: object
```

---

```
s1 = df.groupby('name')['id'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True).to_dict()).dropna()
print (s1)
name   
A     1    0.500000
      2    0.500000
B     5    0.666667
      4    0.333333
C     6    1.000000
Name: id, dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks, but it misses the `id` name inside the list as shown in expected outout

Comment: @TheGreat - is possible create dictionary like EDIT?

Comment: can that dict be stored inside a dataframe column?

Comment: @TheGreat - sure, possible but I used list comprehnsion because different format. Added new solution for MultiIndex Series.

Answer (score 1):

Let us do two groupby's. First `groupby` to calculate normalized counts of `id` per `name` and second one to aggregate normalized counts to `list`

```
df.groupby('name')['id'].value_counts(normalize=True).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

---

```
name
A                                  [0.5, 0.5]
B    [0.6666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333]
C                                       [1.0]
Name: id, dtype: object
```

Comment: but this doesn't show the `id` in the list?

Comment: we want the id and % to be in the same list as in expected output. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to leverage [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to come up with this method

```py
from collections import Counter

id_all = df.groupby("name")["id"].agg(list)

def roundToTwo(value, total):
    value = value / total
    value *= 100
    return round(value, 2)


def get_percentage(item: list) -> list:
    c = Counter(item)
    total = sum(c.values())
    percent = {key: roundToTwo(value, total) for key, value in c.items()}
    return percent 


id_percentage = id_all.apply(lambda item: get_percentage(item))

print(id_percentage.head())
```

Output:

```
name
A      {1: 50.0, 2: 50.0}
B    {5: 66.67, 4: 33.33}
C              {6: 100.0}
```

Comment: nice. In the final output, will you be able to link both `name` and `% for each id`?

Comment: Ah yes, if you were to simply return `percent` you would get a series with the associated dict. You should be able to access those fields as you need to. I have updated the code in the edit