# use pandas col to store % of values in dict format

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as below

```
name,id,AL
A,1,22
A,2,22
B,5,21
B,5,23
B,4,24
C,6,21
```

I would like to do the below

a) Groupby `name`

b) get the unique count (nunique) of `id` and `PL` for each `name`

With the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72542691/pandas-aggregate-list-with-for-each-group), I managed to do the below

```
cols = ['id','PL']
for col in cols:
    d = {i: x.value_counts(normalize=True).to_dict() for i, x in cf.groupby('name')[col]}
print(pd.Series(d))
```

But the above doesn't work for multiple columns (purely due to my limitation)

Is there anyway to make it work for multiple columns? My real data has 5 million rows and I have store count values in a % format under dict (for around 5-6 columns). So, any elegant and efficient solution welcome

I expect my output to be like below

```
name  id_list          AL_list

A    {1:0.5,2:0.5}     {22:1}
B    {5:0.66,4:0.33}   {21:0.33,23:0.33,24:0.33}
C    {6:1.0}           {21:1}
```

**UPDATE - incorrect output based on answer try**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `groupby` with `value_counts` then convert to `dict`

```
out = pd.concat([df.groupby('name')[x].value_counts(normalize=True).round(2).reset_index(level=0).groupby('name').agg(dict) for x in ['id','AL']],axis=1).add_suffix('_list').reset_index()
Out[716]: 
  name             id_list                         AL_list
0    A    {1: 0.5, 2: 0.5}                       {22: 1.0}
1    B  {5: 0.67, 4: 0.33}  {21: 0.33, 23: 0.33, 24: 0.33}
2    C            {6: 1.0}                       {21: 1.0}
```

Comment: nice. but is there anyway to round the percentage values to only two decimals? ex: 0.33 instead of 0.333333333

Comment: @TheGreat check the update add the round

Comment: @TheGreat make sure you read your df by df=pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')

Comment: okay, it worked. My bad. there was a comma missing in input dataframe. do you know how can I show column headers as ony `id_list` and `AL_list`. I don't need `id` and `AL` as 2nd level headers

Comment: what are those 2 level headers called as? I see that you have used `suffix` to select them but let's say if I have to drop them, is there any option to do that? or we only have to select using a pattern like `_list`?

Comment: @TheGreat that is mutiple index for column , so you can drop it with assign , df.column = df.column.get_level_values(0)